# DB2 Database Transfer

Tags: db2

I am trying to move the db2 database from one server to another.
I have done moving all the tables by using export, import and db2move process.

But I am struck at moving views.
There are many view type tables in old database.

Could anyone please tell me the procedure for moving the view type tables from old Database to new Database?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question does not belong to StackOverFlow but Database admins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For db2 object you need to use db2look

Do not create the referential integrity before the load.

Comment: I have used db2look command when moving my database in new system with the help of .ddl file that generated from old database. However it did not create views in my new database.

Comment: You have to check the options to generate your ddl from db2look. I think is -e to generate all objects. Then check the file to look for the views. They should be there